# Residence manager logo feedback

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, branding, identity

I made a logo for my dad's company.
I'm stuck because I can't decide which one to pick. Also it's my first logo so I'm not sure if it's the best.

Background info:

- He is a handyman, but primarily manages a residence.
- He does cleaning and other chores for the residence such as installing a lamp or what not.
- The residence consists of 4 towers. I processed this within the logo. The last tower is the tallest, which is why I made that one so in the logo. Also, he wanted to have a blue color for his brand identity.

I reworked this logo because it had 3 towers. I did this because I liked the ratio of space the logo takes.

[image]

But then I realised a logo should be realistic.

This is the rework (2nd version with variations)
[image]

Comment: Hi Ous. There doesn't seem to be any *actual* question here. You may benefit from reviewing the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and then [editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/117237/edit) your question.

Comment: which logo is better = subjective question. Also logos don't always have to be realistic, for example Apple doesn't sell apples.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a logo for your father's company, which as you describe in the background info it's a service company, it's a bit difficult to decide which logo is the most appropriate because instead of making a logo for your father you have made a logo for the residence.

Maybe you should study well what are the most important conceptual points that define your father's work and from there start to design a logo.

For example, the number of towers and which is the highest is not relevant to perform those services.

On the other side there are important points that are not reflected: handyman, manager, cleaning, installing, or others that can be added such as efficiency in service, professionalism, speed ... I think a conversation with the client (your father), a paper and a pencil would be a great help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I thin you are right and I have to start over again. The main thing he does is managing those 4 towers. But you gave me new insight by telling that is not the focus of the company itself. I guess I have to go brainstorming again and see what I come up with 

Answer (score 0):

Being able to manage a complex seems to be more than to be able to be a handyman. The first contains the ability to get a handyman available as soon as he's needed. Thus a general business logo is more ok than something with a hammer, nails and ladder. That's of course only an opinion. Your father  only knows does he want to present himself as a handyman or as a man who among his other tasks also finds an handyman.

I suggest to forget black, if it must be blue. Also I suggest to put the text part and the rest to the same space. Then both can be bigger, but H&F services seem to rule the houses in the back.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, I really appericiate it. I agree with u as well about the nails and such. His primary job is to manage the residence.